# Question about Bridge edge loops

Tags: modeling, edges

I want to bridge the two following loops:

- a figure $8$ (i.e. two polygons with a common edge)
- a rectangle

After joining the two objects and applying the tool *Bridge edge loops*, I only get one circle bridged.

Does it mean that that tool cannot be applied here? How do I join then the two loops?

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Updated

Comment: Consider adding more geometry to your "plane". Bridge edge loops works best when both loops have the same number of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove/dissolve the edge shared, or the one in the middle, and retry Bridge Edge Loops. Blender has problems with cases such as yours as a loop has to be a **loop**, i.e. is not supposed to be split. And the same number of vertices in both loops does result in better topology